# Linux virtual machines unable to connect to the Internet (Virtual Box)

Tags: windows-7, linux, windows, networking, virtualbox

I'm having difficulties connecting to the Internet from *NIX virtual machines. I have a whonix gateway and workstation, and a kali linux virtual machine running in Sun's Virtual Box. The network settings are shown bellow:

**whonix-gateway:**

[image: gateway1]

[image: gateway2]

**whonix-workstation:**

[image: workstation]

The above configurations are not working when I'm connecting to the Internet through an ethernet cable, using a statically assigned IP address on the host machine. The configuration works when I am using DHCP and connect through a Wi-Fi hotspot.

I also have a virtual machine running windows 7 that connects to the Internet regardless if the host is connected via the ethernet cable or Wi-Fi hotspot. Its configuration is bellow:

**virtual windows 7:**
[image: win7]

The host machine is running x64 windows 7. Why are the linux virtual machines unable to connect to the Internet when the host machine has a static network configuration?

In the above configurations only adapters that are in use are shown.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know too much about Whonix, but sounds like your static / overall network configuration need to be looked at -so others might see where the problem is.  Can you post the following from your various machines (host & guests)?:

- From Windows (command prompt results) -> ipconfig /all
- From GNU/Linux -->  ifconfig && route
- List the static network config details that you changed (ip, masks, gateway, proxies, etc)
- What was errors received?
- Did you try pinging / traceroute your IPs from inside out (localhost, local gateway, router gateway, external ip, external site like google, etc.) to see where stop?

Did you compare your DHCP and static configs to see where might be off?
Your DHCP (network auto-configuration) is good - so static config needs to be changed.

Comment: You shouldn't use the answer field to comment on the question, i.e. ask for more information or suggest how to improve it. Your comment as such is good, I agree we need more information here.